# GEE, Error: Projection error: Unable to compute intersection of geometries in projections SR-ORG:6974

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, error

Im getting this error when trying to "RUN" the exported image to drive.

```
var biomas = ee.FeatureCollection("users/yasminkloosterman/lm_bioma_250");
var pantanal = biomas.filter(ee.Filter.eq('CD_Bioma', 6)
                     );

var BURNED = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MCD64A1")
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-08-01','2019-08-31'))
                    .map(function(img){
                            return img.clip(pantanal.geometry().bounds());
                     })
                    .median()




var NDVI_Unmasked = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD13A2")
                    .select(['NDVI'])
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-07-28'))
                    .map(function(img){
                            return img.clip(pantanal.geometry().bounds())
                                      .multiply(0.0001)
                                      .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start'])
                     })
                     .median()
                     .rename('NDVI Unmasked');



// Thresholding NDVI
var NDVI_mask = NDVI_Unmasked.gt(-3.2767);

// Removing 0 or null values
// 1. selfMask
var self_NDVI_Mask = NDVI_mask.selfMask();

var LST = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/061/MOD11A1")
                    .select('LST_Day_1km')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2019-07-28'))
                    .map(function(img){
                            return img.clip(pantanal.geometry().bounds())
                                      .multiply(0.02)
                                      .subtract(273.15)
                                      .copyProperties(img,['system:time_start'])
                                      ;})
                      .median()
                      .updateMask(self_NDVI_Mask);

// Thresholding LST
var LST_mask = LST.gt(-273.14);

// Removing 0 or null values
// 1. selfMask
var self_LST_Mask = LST_mask.selfMask();


// NDVI MASKED
var NDVI = NDVI_Unmasked.updateMask(self_LST_Mask)
                                .rename('NDVI');



// NDVI
        print(NDVI, 'NDVI')
        Map.addLayer(NDVI, {
          min: 0, max: 1, 
        palette:['FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', 
                '74A901', '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', 
                '004C00', '023B01','012E01', '011D01', '011301']}, 'NDVI');
// LST 
        print(LST, 'LST');
        Map.addLayer(LST, {palette: [
        '4E79C4', '4D89C5', '4E96BB', '539DB3', '59A5A9', '60AB9D', 
        '68B090', '77B77C', '8BBC68', 'A5BE54', 'BDBC48', 'D0B440', 
        'DDA93B', 'E39B39', 'E78C34', 'E57831', 'E4622D', 'DF4728',
        'D92222', 'B8221E', '94211B', '711E17', '521913']}, 'LST');

// TVDI
var TVDI = LST.expression('(LST - 18.71)/((45.969)+(-24.826*NDVI)-(18.71))',
            {'LST': LST,
            'NDVI': NDVI})
            .rename('TVDI')

Map.addLayer(TVDI, {palette: ['2d66a2', '5fabe3', 'ffc310', 'df7c7c', 'a43c3c']}, 'TVDI');
Map.addLayer(BURNED, {}, 'BURNED');
Map.setCenter(-57.683, -20.213,7);



Export.image.toDrive({
  image: TVDI,
  description: 'TVDI_2019-07-28',
  maxPixels: 10e11,
  folder: 'TVDI Images'
});

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: BURNED,
  description: 'BURN_2019-08',
  maxPixels: 10e11,
  folder: 'Burned Areas'
});
```

Comment: Please share the assets in your question (make them public) to make the code in your question reproducible. See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help#gis_stack_exchange

Comment: I tested your code using a simple geometry imported as a FeatureCollection, and the two export tasks were successful. I only commented the first two lines using your asset. See here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/bc2598600265ea859a6e81e903231467